# Sorting list of ints. TMP

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I wonder it it is possible to sort numbers during compilation? I mean something like that:

```
template<int...>
void sort(){
...
}
```

And:

```
sort<2,4,5,13,453>();
```

And I don't ask of solution or something like that. Please give me a hint or reference me.

Comment: Did you try googling "sort variadic list of ints c++"?  It should have brought up [Quick sort at compilation time using C++11 variadic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188182/quick-sort-at-compilation-time-using-c11-variadic-templates).

Comment: Note that this problem is easy in C++14 with relaxed constexpr, and more annoying in C++11.  And the answer is yes, as TMP is turing-complete.  Plus I've done it before.

Comment: TMP is turning complete, you can calculate anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++ template system is known to be turing-complete, you can in principle compute everything that is computable at compile time.  That includes sorting algorithms.